# Need clarification for conda environments and packages

Tags: pip, conda

I made a new environment with

```
conda create --name name python
```

I activated this environment

```
conda activate name
```

I installed a package with pip

```
pip install package
```

I added this new environment to available kernels in jupyter notebook

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=name
```

I created a new notebook and have chosen as a kernel the new environment "name". But when I tried to import the package "package" I had installed it gave me an error that there was no such package.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: One thing I see at first glance is you didn’t include pip or ipykernel at creation. I believe that Python usually brings pip along as a dependency, but if I’m wrong that could explain the behavior. Try instead, `conda create -n name python pip ipykernel`